# How does Superman conceal his identity with just a pair of glasses?

Tags: dc, superman

Almost every other superhero has a mask or a hood to hide their secret identity. But all Clark Kent uses is a pair of glasses. Is that enough to conceal the identity? What is the logic behind this?

Comment: They're epic glasses of "you can't see who I really am"

Comment: Canonically, it's more than just glasses. He also constantly slouches and acts characteristically different from Superman. It's amazing how much difference posture can make; just look at how rapidly trained actors can change how you view them with minor modifications.

Comment: @SeanDuggan: tremendous case in point being Christopher Reeve playing Superman. He totally nails it.

Comment: I went to a school reunion a couple of years ago. At high school I always wore (very nerdy) glasses because I was particularly short-sighted. About ten years ago I had laser surgery, so I was glasses-free at the reunion. No-one recognized me.

Comment: fun joke is the glass is actually krypton's product which bend the face other see him when they see the glass like an illusion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this article explains brillantly why he uses just glasses 
http://witnessing101.hubpages.com/hub/Why-Supermans-Costume-Actually-Makes-Sense

of course there is the other side of the arguement that superman is the true persona
Superman stands alone. Superman did not become Superman, Superman was born Superman. When Superman wakes up in the morning, he is Superman. His alter ego is Clark Kent. His outfit with the big red S is the blanket he was wrapped in as a baby when the Kents found him. Those are his clothes.
What Kent wears, the glasses the business suit, that's the costume.
That's the costume Superman wears to blend in with us. Clark Kent is how Superman views us. And what are the characteristics of Clark Kent? He's weak, unsure of himself... he's a coward

Comment: Your second paragraph is lifted directly from *Kill Bill: Volume 2*. You might want to give credit where it's due, and explain why that excellent quote is relevant to the original question. Also, a brief description or paraphrase of the answer in your link might be good.

Comment: I think you underestimate Clark's view of humans.  Yes he sees them as frail, clumbsy beings in need of help, but he also portrays himself as a hard-working, earnest news reporter eager to do what he can to prove himself decent while still being a good man to those around him.  In short, he's everything he wishes every man could be.

Answer (score 3):

That is actually [a trope in itself](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ClarkKenting) <sup>(Warning! Link to TVTropes, a known time sink.)</sup>. There are many, *many* explanations (superior facial muscle control, costume distracting from the face, mild hypnotic abilities) given under the trope namer heading. Pick any one you like.

Comment: True, but we prefer Stack Exchange answers to stand on their own, rather than just linking to content elsewhere.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Agreed, but I wanted to convey that there's a plethora of explanations, all equally likely.

Comment: gotcha. A list of a few of them would improve the answer.